# NextAuth redirect on user creation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, next-auth

I am working on a project with NextAuth and after the user creation I need to create and let the user configure the account with Stripe Connect, to achieve this I need the user to be redirected to a certain page only when the user is created (as the documentation of Stripe says [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide?platform=web#redirect-your-user-to-the-account-link-url)), how can I achieve this? I was thinking about using the createUser callback in the NextAuth options but it does not seem to be the correct approach.

The following is my NextAuth options:

```
const options = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
    TwitchProvider({
      clientId: process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_SECRET
    })
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin'
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      console.log("USER SIGNED IN, ", user, account);
      // const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({})
      // const account = await stripe.accounts.retrieve();
      return true;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl;
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      return { ...session, ...user };
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      return token;
    }
  },
  events: {
    createUser: async ({ user }) => {
      console.log("USER CREATED, ", user);

      const customer = await stripe.customers.create({ email: user.email });
      const account = await stripe.accounts.create({ type: "standard" });

      const accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
        account: account.id,
        refresh_url: process.env.PUBLIC_URL,
        return_url: process.env.PUBLIC_URL,
        type: 'account_onboarding',
      });

      await prisma.user.update({
        where: { id: user.id },
        data: {
          customerId: customer.id,
          stripeAccountId: account.id
        },
      });
    }
  },
  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: 'next-auth.session-token',
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        domain: hostName
      },
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callbackUrl in the signIn method
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl

the user will get redirected there when he first logs in

if the user is logging in for the first time it will first create the user and then redirect the new user to the specified URL in the callbackUrl.